# SQL: How to disable result of aggregate on empty table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When applying SQL aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `MAX`, etc.) on an empty table, I would like to get an empty result set (no rows) to simplify processing in the ORM.

Currently, the special return values (`0` for `COUNT`, `NULL` for all other aggregates) [are returned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25435) (assuming an empty table `user`):

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user;
count(id)
0
```

I know there is the trick to use `GROUP BY` plus `HAVING` clause to filter empty results, but this is rather cumbersome and I am unsure about performance:

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user GROUP BY 1=1 HAVING COUNT(id) > 0;
sqlite>
```

Thus the questions:

- Is it possible to disable aggregate functions to return a row if the source table is empty?
- Is there a performance impact of using a GROUP BY clause that true for all entries?

Comment: HAVING without GROUP BY is not supported by sqlite (at least). I was wondering more about the performance impact when the source set is large.

Answer (score 2):

A SQL aggregation query with no `group by` returns one row.  This is *by definition*.  It is how SQL works.  Usually, this is considered a good thing and actually makes applications work better.

For instance, it is easier to check that a single column `count`, rather than checking `count` (if there are rows) and checking for no rows (in other cases).

In SQLite, you can do what you want by adding a `GROUP BY`.  So:

```
select . . . -- aggregation functions only
from . . .
group by null;
```

This is grouping by a constant, which is functionally equivalent to no `group by`, unless there are no rows.  This version returns an empty result set.

Comment: The HAVING is not needed.

Comment: If there are no rows in the table, or left after the WHERE, the result is empty anyway, even without the HAVING.