# MYSQL: Stop IFNULL returning "empty" rows of null

Tags: mysql, ifnull

I'm using IFNULL in the following way:

```
SELECT name, address, birthday, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(pet_name), 'none') AS `pets_names` FROM pets WHERE user_id = 1;
```

However, If I have no user 1, and therefore no results, I will get a single row where all fields are null apart from pet_names which will say 'none'. I tried setting it to only give a value if user_id IS NOT NULL but then I got a row with every value as NULL. How can I get it to just not return any rows when using IFNULL?

Comment: *If I have no user 1, and therefore no results, I will get a single row where all fields are null apart from pet_names which will say 'none'.* Impossible. You must receive empty set, without rows at all. If you see a row with nulls and 'none' then this is your client "service".

Comment: This is what I get on Sequel Pro as well as via the service

Comment: Try the same via CLI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: How to disable result of aggregate on empty table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514329/sql-how-to-disable-result-of-aggregate-on-empty-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding

```
GROUP BY name
```

I presume because there are no names, there's nothing to group by and thus no results.